# Excel - Automatically fill trend values

Tags: excel

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Tele()

    Dim rowLoop As Long
    rowLoop = 1
    strValueToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter a Search value in format xx.xx.xxxx, remember that this will only work if you are on 'Tidal' tab", Title:="DATE FIND", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)

    'Select the sheets to work through
    Sheets(Array("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")).Select

    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

      Debug.Print "Checking " & ws.Name

      ' Loop column A to find value, number corrosponds to letter position in alphabet
      For rowLoop = 1 To Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Value = strValueToFind Then ' If value is in C then do something
          ' start on cell found from date needed - look at copying range on same Column
          ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C09").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C10").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 3).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C11").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 5).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C12").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 7).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C14").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(1, 2).Resize(1).Value
          ' Copy cells 1 cell below found value - Montrose?
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D09").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D10").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 4).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D11").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 6).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D12").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 8).Resize(1).Value
          MsgBox ("Found value on col " & rowLoop) '
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Next rowLoop ' This is row number, do something with this

    'Back for next sheet
    Next ws

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Date not found, make sure you have input the date correctly and on the right tab")

End Sub
```

This program lets the user input the date and return the tide times and heights on that day. Additionally the user needs to input a time and have the equivalent tide height returned to them. The problem is that I only have 4 values, not a value for every single day. So consider this:

Say I have a table like this: (Assume Tidal Time is A and Tidal Height is B)

```
Tidal Time  Tidal Height  
01:00   
02:00   
03:00   
04:00   
05:00            5  
06:00   
07:00   
08:00   
09:00   
10:00   
11:00            1.2  
12:00   
13:00   
14:00   
15:00   
16:00   
17:00            5.2  
18:00   
19:00   
20:00   
21:00   
22:00   
23:00            1.1  
00:00
```

Would it be possible to fill in the unknown values based on the inputted values.
**Note:** 
There are only ever 3 or 4 values filled in.
These appear at different times for different sets of data.

Actually i've done this already by using the fill right click series (trend) command, what I need this to do is run automatically once these values change.

**To clarify:**
'fil in' refers to In the unfilled values in Column B. Like.. It needs to trend from whatever value is inputted to the next values and vice versa. An extrapolation if you will. Furthermore it needs to happen automatically based on which cells are filled

**The reason for this functionality written as simply as I can manage:**
The data gives 4 values per day.
- 4 times and 4 tide heights.
- User puts in the date and these 4 values fill themselves in at B next to the closest time.
- The table needs to extrapolate itself out to fill in the unwritten values.
- Then when the time is put in. It checks the time with all the values in B.   Anything above 3.2 on the returned value (the tide height) which corrosponds to the inputted time gives a 'yes', anything below gives a 'no'

**Forecast equivalent:**
So for the last part where I give yes or no, I was thinking of a forecast function: `=FORECAST(00:45,A10:A33,B10:B33)`
Where the 00:45 is the time inputted by the user, and the forecast is made on the information inputted in B. Ideally I need the VBA equivalent of this so that 00:45 can be value a `Application.InputBox`

Comment: "fill in the unknown values", fill where? Your question is not clear.

Comment: In the unfilled spaces. Like.. It needs to trend from whatever value is inputted to the next values and vice versa. An extrapolation if you will. Furthermore it needs to happen automatically based on which cells are inputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either enter formulas based on whatever basis you estimate the values on, e.g. if it is linear:

(Cells references assume the top left of your example is A1)

in B7:
=B6-(($B$6-$B$12)/6)

then drag down to the next figure. Then do the same for B12 and B18 and so on. The values will automatically update.

**Edit:** To answer the other part of your question, you would need to lookup the time after rounding up to the nearest hour. Something like, if the date is entered in D35 and the sheet given in your question is sheet1:

Lookup(D35,sheet1!$A$1:$A$24,3,1)

If this doesn't work check that all the times are actually formatted as times. If you need to round to the nearest hour try TIME(HOUR(D35)+IF(MINUTE(D35)>30,1,0),0,0)

Then, in column C use an if statement to discern if the values are greater than 3.2 e.g. in C2: =IF(B2>3.2,"yes","no")

The lookup should return yes or no.

Comment: Awesome can this be done in visual basic so that I can set a dynamically changing value?  

For example, four values have been put in so it trends automatically on all the other cells?  

It's difficult because the trending line has two average points. and the values that are inputted in B change occording to the tide time at the time, the maths breaks down once that happens.

Comment: Where are the values sourced from? Does it delete out all the other values automatically? I think if this is the case you may need to write a visual basic macro in the worksheet which is triggered by the change in the worksheet, finds the values that have been filled in, calculates and inputs. You would need to put the macro in the worksheet itself with the following syntax:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

Comment: So basically the data gives 4 values per day. 4 times and 4 tide heights. User puts in the date and these 4 values fill themselves in at B next to the right or closest time. The table needs to extrapolate itself out to fill in the unwritten values. Then when the time is put in. It checks the time with all the values in B. Anything above 3.2 on the returned value (the tide height) which corrosponds to the inputted time gives an 'yes', anything below give a 'no'.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with a macro assigned to a button, so that it is executed once the user has manually inputted all the values. It could loop through, inserting formulas similar to those I suggested. The only question is how it behaves between 00:00 and 01:00 - should it be extrapolating from the previous days last value to the first value for today, or should it be wrapping the values for the single day round?

Comment: Ah see that's another thing I've just considered. I can pull in the value from the previous day easily with an extra line of code under the other offset pasted values. It should be extrapolating from the preview days last value, which is another problem I don't know the answer too. Man this is complicated. So the loop checks the values inputted, and based off those values insert the formulas? The maths of that sounds hairy! I cannot visualise data in that way aha. See this is why I don't do databases! Thank you so much for all the help thus far btw